# How can I get long texts to automatically span over several columns?

Tags: html, css

I would like to get the same behaviour that you get in Microsoft Word with several columns. When column 1 is filled, the text automatically starts in column 2.

I figured there would be a tag or technique on how to do this, but google gave me no usable results.

The obvious workaround would be to manually place text in three columns, but the would be a ton of work when changing the layout or font size.

Any advice?

Thanks - Codemonkey

Comment: I think you're trying to accomplish something HTML is not suited to.  I do not believe you can accomplish auto-flow to separate columns - the tag based nature of HTML is going to restrict you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 has a [multi-column feature](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) that does exactly this. Setting `column-count: n` will split the text into `n` columns.

Since CSS3 isn't standardized yet, Mozilla and Webkit use the `-moz-column-count` and `-webkit-column-count` properties instead. Of course, IE doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with JavaScript.  I am not aware of any pure-CSS techniques that can do this.